# Reverse proxy to WordPress container

Tags: wordpress, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a `WordPress` container via Docker. But I have `NGINX`, `MySQL` and `Let's Encrypt` installed on the `host` level.

So, my Docker Compose file is:

```
wordpress:
  image: wordpress:latest
  restart: always
  net: "host"
  environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: 172.17.0.1:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: DB_NAME
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: DB_USER
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: DB_PASSWORD
  ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/wordpress:/var/www/html
```

and my NGINX config is:

```
server {
    listen                                      80 443 ssl http2;

    server_name                                 domain.com www.domain.com;

    # some headers

    ssl                                         on;
    # some ssl settings

    gzip                                        on;
    # some gzip settings

    # pagespeed and let's encrypt locations

    location / {
        if ($scheme = http) {
            return 301                          https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }

        # proxy pass headers

        proxy_pass                              http://172.17.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

and finally, my `ifconfig` output is:

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:24:ad:a2:e8:dd  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::24:adff:fea2:e8dd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:334 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:20589 (20.5 KB)  TX bytes:10261280 (10.2 MB)
```

But when I open `domain.com`, I got redirected to `https://domain.com` with `502 Bad Gateway`.

One final output from `docker-compose logs`:

```
Attaching to ubuntu_wordpress_1
wordpress_1  | (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
wordpress_1  | (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
wordpress_1  | no listening sockets available, shutting down
wordpress_1  | AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

---

So, what I'm trying to do is containerise WordPress via Docker and whenever there's a request to 80 port, redirecting that to Docker container.

Restrictions:

- I don't want to Dockerize MySQL, that's final.
- I don't want to Dockerize NGINX, because I personally like to build it from source with `http2` and `pagespeed` modules.

Comment: Make docker listen to 8080 (the port you're proxying to) only instead of 80 which nginx listens to

Comment: Hello @IgorYavych I saw it when you commented, and fixed. But still, I'm getting `Address already in use` error. So, nothing changed. Even if it's "8080:8080" in the yml file, it tries to bind to 0.0.0.0:80 and it's in use by NGINX.

Comment: After changing to `8080:8080` you are still having some `could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80` ? You tried `docker-compose down && docker-compose up`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is about network configuration I suppose. Your container uses port 80 for wordpress and your host uses the same port for nginx. When you use net: "host"(https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/network-settings), your container uses the host's network stack and they conflict trying to bind to the same port.

If your mysql server is remotely accessible just remove the net: "host" part and replace the mysql host configuration to how you would connect to it remotely. It should just work.

If it's not possible to open your mysql to remote connections for any reason, then I guess you should go through creating what called a user-defined network. It can be configured via docker-compose.yml file as well. (https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specifying-custom-networks)

Comment: Thanks A LOT! I removed `net: "host"` line and updated `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST` to connect remotely, and voilà!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```html
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:4.8.2-apache
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    restart: always
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=blog.dom.local
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
```